# Getting error from C# server code while making request through $.ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using `$.ajax` to send request to C# code in Asp.Net.Each time i am getting the error in the response(checked in Firebug) like:

```
{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: EmailAddress.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}
```

If i remove `data:{}` parameter from the `$.ajax` then it is fine.I think there is some problem with my way of sending data to the server.

My Client side code is:
 
function send_req() {

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "Demo.aspx/Demo_Method",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"EmailAddress": "abc@testmail.com"},
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Success' + response);
            }
        });
    }
```

And Demo.aspx.cs page code is:

```
public partial class Demo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [WebMethod()]
    public static void Demo_Method(string EmailAddress)
    {
        //Some code....

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an overloaded method "void Demo_Method(int something)"?

Comment: No only these two methods are there:void Page_Loda() and Void Demo_Method(string EmailAddress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my calls, I specify `dataType: "json"`, and wrap the whole `data` parameter in quotes.

e.g.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "Demo.aspx/Demo_Method",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{'EmailAddress':'abc@testmail.com'}",
        success: function (response) {
            alert('Success' + response);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove quotation mark around `EmailAddress` parameter:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "Demo.aspx/Demo_Method",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
   type: "POST",
   data: {EmailAddress: "abc@testmail.com"},
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^

   success: function (response) {
         alert('Success' + response);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the data as string, not as object.

example:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "Demo.aspx/Demo_Method",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        type: "POST",
        data:  '{"EmailAddress": "abc@testmail.com"}',
        success: function (response) {
            alert('Success' + response);
        }
    });
```